# WiX ManagedBootstrapper SetDownloadSource confusion

Tags: wix, wix3.6, burn

I am a bit confused by the method Engine.SetDownloadSource(). What I am trying to do is change the download URL for the bundled packages from an external website to an internal one. (If there is an easier way to do this, I am open to other suggestions).

Now for the problem. When calling this method it is asking for a user and password. I am not sure where I should get this info from.

```
string downloadSource = Path.Combine(WebSitePath(), "WebSetup/WebSetupData/", Path.GetFileName(args.DownloadSource));

Engine.SetDownloadSource(args.PackageOrContainerId, args.PayloadId, downloadSource, user, password);
```

WebSitePath() simply returns the base URL for the website. I can't find any hint about what username and password the MBA would use if I didn't change the link, and likewise I am not sure how to tell it to use the current windows user to download from the new link. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Username and password are optional to support basic or digest HTTP authorization. Set them to null if you don't want to provide a user/password combination.